# How to open multiple files from desktop in the same emacs session?

Tags: server, session

I use Pop OS 20.04 on my desktop. When I start Emacs on login, I run the command `(server-start)`. So when I open a file using the command `emacsclient <filename>` it opens it in the currently running emacs session. I love this.

However, when I double click text files in the native file explorer a new Emacs session is started. How do I force all files to open in the same Emacs session?

Answer (score 1):

The details will depend on the particular file browser you're using, but you need to set the default program for opening text files to `emacsclient`, rather than `emacs`.

Comment: Thank you. How do we do that? PopOS runs GNOME.
I can't even set Emacs as the default editor. And I have tried updating the ```defaults.list``` and the ```update-alternatives``` method suggested on this site elsewhere.

The best I could do was select Emacs as the default editor for ```.org``` files from the GUI. But I couldn't enforce Emacs to be the default editor for the system. Gedit is the default editor for my system.

Comment: I don't know. That would be a good question for a Pop OS forum, I'm not familiar with it